# Dart and Live plugins

Tags: plugins, content-management-system, dart

So one of the neat features of languages like PHP is that you can include other files pragmatically and make a plugin-like system. I haven't seen an example of it yet, so I am not sure it is technically possible in Dart, but I would like to start designing a CMS that can load and unload plugins live without restarting or a fresh upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is only possible to load/unload code dynamically using Isolates.
In the browser new isolates don't have access to the DOM and it is limited which types can be passed between isolates. What can be serialized to JSON can be passed between isolates easily but for custom types you need to serialize yourself. I'm not sure about the actual limitations here though, this is work in progress.

In the browser the current limitations make it hard to make use of isolates. You can't load code into an isolate that imports 'dart:html' this prevents the use any browser API. On the server there are no such limitations.

This should all be improved but currently there are still a lot of limitations.

Comment: Well the plugins I would create would be done through a console app, so no need for the DOM on this end.

Comment: On server side this works quite well already. Also debugging isolates should be fixed by now (haven't tried it yet).